# How to squash core data migrations?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, core-data-migration

I have an app for which I generate a seed core data database in a Mac command line program with Xcode. During beta-testing I used several model versions. Now, for the first release of the app, I want to squash the versions into one model with version 1. *Is that even possible?*

**I removed the old model versions from the xcdatamodeld folder and set the current version to the initial one. I removed both references to the old model versions from the pbxproj file.** Regardless of what I try, I get a "Persistent store migration failed, missing mapping model."-error. I tried everything listed [here](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4-and-later), namely:

- cleaned project, exit Xcode
- remove generated database from documents folder
- remove binaries
- remove all Derived Data
- run `rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"`
- delete cache from `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode`

Nothing helped. I am wondering from where Xcode could know about the old model... For clarification, this is referring to the database creation tool I run as a command line app on the mac, not the iOS app itself.

*Other ways to squash the db are well appreciated.* One alternative I am considering is renaming the database and ignoring the old one from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not figure out how XCode knows about the old model, I went with creating the model again with a different name and adapting the urls in code. This works without a problem.

EDIT: I finally figured it out - my self-built command line app was properly installed and thus had its own directory under `~/Library/Application Support/<name of your app>/` where its three `*.sqlite` files were residing. Deleting them finally got rid of the "missing mapping model" error.